# Microsoft bot framework v.4 -- pass data from one dilogflow to another

Tags: c#, dialog, chat, botframework, bots

I am trying to pass data between 2 dialogs in MS Bot Framework 4. But, Its not working. I have used stepContext.Values. But it can not forward data to another Dialog. I am a kind of new in Microsoft bot Framework. Would be appreciated if someone can help me.

### First Dialog:

```
public class Step1Dialog : WaterfallDialog
{
    public Step1Dialog(string dialogId, string dataA, IEnumerable<WaterfallStep> steps = null) : base(dialogId, steps)
    {
        AddStep(async (stepContext, cancellationToken) =>
        {              
            var choices = new List<Choice>();

            for (int i = 1; i<3; i++)
            {
                choices.Add(new Choice { Value = "" + i.ToString()});
            }

            PromptOptions _choicePromptOptions = new PromptOptions { Choices = choices, Prompt = stepContext.Context.Activity.CreateReply("What type of help you want? \n 1. Help 1\n 2. Help 2" ) };

            return await stepContext.PromptAsync("choicePrompt", _choicePromptOptions);

        });

        AddStep(async (stepContext, cancellationToken) =>
        {
            stepContext.Values["mamun1"].Equals("Mamun");

            var response = (stepContext.Result as FoundChoice)?.Value;

            if (response == "1")
            {
                return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(Help1.Id);
            }

            if (response == "2")
            {
                return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(Help2.Id);
            }

            return await stepContext.NextAsync();
        });

        AddStep(async (stepContext, cancellationToken) => { return await stepContext.ReplaceDialogAsync(Id); });
    }

    public static string Id => "step1Dialog";
    public static string data;
    public static Step1Dialog Instance { get;} = new Step1Dialog(Id,data);
}
```

### Second Dialog:

```
public class Help1 : WaterfallDialog
{
    public Help1(string dialogId, string dataA, IEnumerable<WaterfallStep> steps = null) : base(dialogId, steps)
    {
        AddStep(async (stepContext, cancellationToken) =>
        {
            string msgFromPreviousDilog = (string) stepContext.Values["mamun1"];
            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync($"Hi" + msgFromPreviousDilog );
            return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync();
        });

        AddStep(async (stepContext, cancellationToken) => { return await stepContext.ReplaceDialogAsync(Id); });
    }

    public static string Id => "help1";
    public static string data;
    public static Help1 Instance { get;} = new Help1(Id,data);
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you share where you're getting your code from? Are you following a tutorial or anything?

Comment: I should mention that `Equals` performs a comparison, not an assignment

Comment: Hi This is standard dialog coding that I got from Microsoft default example.

Comment: What default example? Are you saying this is part of a VSIX template? Which one?

Comment: yes its VSIX template. But i edited according to my needs.

Comment: In the VSIX templates I've seen, all the custom dialog classes extend `ComponentDialog`, not `WaterfallDialog`. Do you remember which VSIX template you used?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options here. I'll explain two of them.

#### Option 1: Dialog options

First, you would pass the data as an argument of `BeginDialogAsync`:

```
return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(Help1.Id, "Mamun");
```

Then you would retrieve the data using the state of the `DialogInstance`:

```
string msgFromPreviousDilog = (string)stepContext.ActiveDialog.State["options"];
```

Note that the data you pass as a dialog's options persists between turns.

#### Option 2: Turn state

If you don't need the data to persist between turns, you can always use turn state. You can add data to turn state like this:

```
stepContext.Context.TurnState.Add("mamun1", "Mamun");
```

And you can retrieve it like this:

```
string msgFromPreviousDilog = (string)stepContext.Context.TurnState["mamun1"];
```